# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8024: character maps to <undefined> when re-directing output to disk

Tags: windows, httpie

On Windows 10, I'm using httpie to retrieve data.  It works fine when displaying on the screen, but as soon as I pipe the output to disk, I get
*http: error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8024: character maps to `<undefined>`*

Is there a way to change the encoding when writing to disk?

Here is the complete debug output:

```
>> http --debug --print=Bb --pretty=all --session=C:\Users\PETERK~1\AppData\Local\Temp/access.json http://localhost:8080/nexus/extract/path  filePath=c:/TestFiles/100Mb.pdf > foo
HTTPie 2.3.0
Requests 2.25.1
Pygments 2.7.3
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
c:\python\python39\python.exe
Windows 10

<Environment {'colors': 256,
 'config': {'default_options': []},
 'config_dir': WindowsPath('C:/Users/PeterKronenberg/AppData/Roaming/httpie'),
 'devnull': <property object at 0x000001112C1815E0>,
 'is_windows': True,
 'log_error': <function Environment.log_error at 0x000001112C1AC1F0>,
 'program_name': 'http',
 'stderr': <colorama.ansitowin32.StreamWrapper object at 0x000001112C176F10>,
 'stderr_isatty': True,
 'stdin': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>,
 'stdin_encoding': 'utf-8',
 'stdin_isatty': True,
 'stdout': <colorama.ansitowin32.StreamWrapper object at 0x000001112C176BE0>,
 'stdout_encoding': 'cp1252',
 'stdout_isatty': False}>

>>> requests.request(**{'auth': None,
 'data': '{"filePath": "c:/TestFiles/100Mb.pdf"}',
 'headers': {'User-Agent': b'HTTPie/2.3.0', 'Accept': b'application/json, */*;q=0.5', 'Content-Type': b'application/json', 'authorization': b'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InB1YmxpYzplMjM3ODE1Ny04MmY0LTQ2YjItYWI5NS1hMDRhMzg4ZGY5ZTQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOltdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiIxMTExMTExMS0xMTExLTExMTEtMTExMS0xMTExMTExMTExMTUiLCJleHAiOjE2MDk0NDAxNzYsImV4dCI6e30sImlhdCI6MTYwOTQzNjU3NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9vaWRjLnRvcmNoLmFpLyIsImp0aSI6IjZkN2QwOTFkLTQyMTctNGRmMS04ZmY3LTk2MDdiMzkzZjBlZCIsIm5iZiI6MTYwOTQzNjU3Niwic2NwIjpbXSwic3ViIjoiMTExMTExMTEtMTExMS0xMTExLTExMTEtMTExMTExMTExMTE1In0.QeCNhpoE-1UyLcHer2_JjhiMx3qKV1qIC3LX0rlRUKSIK5vlMbJ2KmVP1mNR647SJhAxN9zdqf9vDaG6Fk0ZRLBFSBbcq0WuyTlaJsPVVggpe9ys_mcqO8uPMTl4-tO0H5kXVzRi_TFcmfCH8W3X8KAe3K7kjfs8O207EAenPr8n-KB12qUQgpC4ELXRbC_9SwuZY_ZhOic9POUYMCvrmJkMB8Th4kOqix5uI45lwowVQI9kTgAB4kQF8VelYJF7xxxn81U24T3ab9lRtp6ShY1mUkhDwfhrz2YdhYQ4uhQhKNZc3Hxz8OPSV_0Q-ykdZVgi03su51E_SE0odnryiUrR4nheu1cxmGmKNq8gb2CII9NktgrZEvvXlYJ5cV5mI2AAVlgkp4A0FBCd_wt39mXadIWPjv3YfilkzwUZCoeKA8dpp1mOKebFjq7Iw4LnxhObuKw1BnhYjHzdtQC5mhwFtc5iCeYChkQG_b8vybap12S4HzQ7HHFBKjdJZ2Il5mbuF01BAUBhZ1TO2GQ_t3O0JVrp8rmob75Yiza5FiBZaeAASSp2p0mb-_CmTVnQq3N-f099yL7byNYKl0toLIfgDLuib6bv_rhushdvEyWOD1c-nJnqMNFekEZ4NXTvBskL9PJCWcW-r8l1Fn567s7SAFan-G37YeQYBfmwADI'},
 'method': 'post',
 'params': <generator object MultiValueOrderedDict.items at 0x000001112CA5FB30>,
 'url': 'http://localhost:8080/nexus/extract/path'})


http: error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1617: character maps to <undefined>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\Scripts\http.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\httpie\__main__.py", line 11, in main
    exit_status = main()
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\httpie\core.py", line 79, in main
    exit_status = program(
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\httpie\core.py", line 222, in program
    write_message(
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\httpie\output\writer.py", line 38, in write_message
    write_stream_with_colors_win_py3(**write_stream_kwargs)
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\httpie\output\writer.py", line 82, in write_stream_with_colors_win_py3
    outfile.write(chunk.decode(encoding))
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1617: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Would you post the full traceback so it's visible which [of the writers](https://github.com/httpie/httpie/blob/master/httpie/output/writer.py) you are using?

Comment: The traceback would be helpful indeed. You can get it by adding the `--debug` option. In any case, this looks like a bug, so please feel free to open a new issue — https://github.com/httpie/httpie/issues/new. Just please include the entire command as well as the output.

Comment: I updated the question with the debug output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPie is taking encoding from the system's `stdout` configuration. You have it configured for `Windows 1252` and trying to write down data out of its capabilities (presumably `utf8`).

While HTTPie doesn't provide an option to separately configure the writer's output encoding, you can set output's default through `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable. Try this

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 http --debug --print=Bb --pretty=all --session=C:\Users\PETERK~1\AppData\Local\Temp/access.json http://localhost:8080/nexus/extract/path  filePath=c:/TestFiles/100Mb.pdf > foo
```

I am actually not too familiar with Windows—if this wouldn't work, set run this before running HTTPie:

```
setx PYTHONIOENCODING "utf-8"
```

Note this will override encoding for all other Python scripts for this command line session.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Yes, this did fix the problem.  Thank you